# iOS change UIView type without redoing autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I created a layout and put all auto-layout constraints among the views, but I need one UILabel to be changed to UIButton.

because I don't want to alter the view further, is there any way to directly alter view types (UILabel->UIButton) keeping the auto-layout constraints as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. Your best bet is placing a hidden UIButton behind the UILabel with the exact same constraints and swapping the hidden state when the change is needed.

Another alternative I can think of is setting a button have a clear background, disabling the button and making it APPEAR like a label, then when the button is needed, change all the properties back to make the button look and behave like a button again.